# What is the event in cocoa for NSWindow that tells that NSWindow is now displayed after first run?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to show a sheet dialog soon after the main window has been shown after first run. If I do it in the init or awake from nib , it does not seem to work right (sheet show as window detached from main window if I do it in the init method). I guess I have to show sheet once the parent window has shown. I have an appcontroller class which has a window pointer. So I guess I need to register as a delegate or something with window ? and implement some method to receive that call ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`applicationDidFinishLaunching:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW3) is your entry point. It is sent to your app delegate after the app is all set up, but before the user has had a chance to interact with it.

Comment: Worth emphasizing that this is per-application, not per-window. If you close and reopen the window, you don't get `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` again, because that only happens once and it already did happen. If you need to do whatever you need to do any time the *window* is shown, not only when the application finishes launching, then you need something to be the window's delegate and respond to the correct delegate message for that.

Comment: @Ahmed, Peter Hosey's warning is quite correct. My answer only works for the very first time the window is shown when the app launches.

Comment: @PeterHosey Thanks for your valuable comments, for my current case Josh Caswell's answer works, but defintely your advice is very helpful I am now looking at this stuff in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reliable event, notification, or delegate method call. It is expected that your code is responsible for showing the window, so it should already know when the window is shown.

Are you relying on the Visible at Launch property set in Interface Builder? If so, what you using to load the NIB? Hopefully, a window controller. In that case, you should be calling the `-window` method to load the NIB and obtain the window. The resulting window reference is what you would pass to the method that begins the sheet.

If not relying on Visible at Launch, what code are you using to show the window? For example, invoking `-showWindow:` on the window controller? So, put the code to show the sheet right after that.

Comment: I have 'Visible at launch checked' so yes I am relying on that. Regarding what I am doing to load window Nib, nothing, if you just create a new cocoa project in xcode and run it, a window shows up. nib is automatically loaded and window pointer in the AppDelgate class. Also I can already create sheet with button on the window, but I wanted to show it exactly after window was displayed. @Josh Caswell's answer worked for me

Comment: @Ahmed: Having the window in your MainMenu nib with “Visible at launch” turned on will work for the simplest of purposes, but if you need to customize that at all, it's time to move that window to a separate nib and make a window controller to own it and be the window's delegate. I typically just do it right away unconditionally rather than have to move it later.